# Exoplayer start it with intent in fullscreen mode

Tags: java, android, android-layout, user-interface, exoplayer

I'm trying to start Exoplayer via intent in fullscreen mode.

Simply pass the parameters to the intent, such as url and the possible title.

I tried looking in the documentation and on stackoverflow, but I could not find anything.

This is the code I am currently using, but with poor results.

```
try {

            BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();
            TrackSelector trackSelector = new DefaultTrackSelector(new AdaptiveTrackSelection.Factory(bandwidthMeter));
            exoPlayer = ExoPlayerFactory.newSimpleInstance(this, trackSelector);

            Uri videoURI = Uri.parse(url);

            DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory("exoplayer_video");
            ExtractorsFactory extractorsFactory = new DefaultExtractorsFactory();
            MediaSource mediaSource = new ExtractorMediaSource(videoURI, dataSourceFactory, extractorsFactory, null, null);

            exoPlayerView.setPlayer(exoPlayer);
            exoPlayer.prepare(mediaSource);
            exoPlayer.setPlayWhenReady(true);
            exoPlayerView.setResizeMode(AspectRatioFrameLayout.RESIZE_MODE_FILL);

        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.e("MainAcvtivity"," exoplayer error "+ e.toString());
        }
```

Can someone give me a hand?

Answer (score 2):

Exoplayer is a really good player in all terms except full screen, so best way to deal with fullscreen functionality is to have a activity with orientation of only landscape, or if you want to have both portrait and landscape mode its better to change orientation. Check this article
https://medium.com/tall-programmer/fullscreen-functionality-with-android-exoplayer-5fddad45509f
But if you don't want to handle these stuff i  recommend you to change player to JWPlayer or youtubeplayer.

Comment: Meanwhile, I thank you for answering.
The videos I have to play are not youtube videos, so I need a generic player where I can edit the ui and I have to run it in fullscreen mode.
The type of graphics I would like to create is this: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Vg-C_LYVvCW9gqXpfGPB5Fg6h_ekAx29/view
What do you recommend, to continue using exoplayer?

Comment: Yeah exoplayer is one of the best player but if you only want to deal with fullscreen, then my recommendation would be brightcove-exoplayer, it is derived from exoplayer and moreover they have the best documentation of all player and it may fulfill your usecase. Try to work with it.

Comment: This is what I was able to do at the moment by modifying the exoplayer graphics: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AdGrMFLHxR3xi32uA3IKB7AUXElHXTQa/view
even if the thing of the circles still does not satisfy me, what do you think?

The problem I would like to use this for the seekbar preview: https://github.com/rubensousa/PreviewSeekBar

I read the article you indicated, but I miss some things: for example what should I put in FullscreenVideoActivity.java and MainActivity.java?

Do you know where I can find all the complete sample code?

Comment: ok, I would like tell once it is completed it would look cool. Then so you want to launch the the exoplayer via intent, so that intent should be your fullscreen activity, and all the launching of intent and whatever you are doing before that should go in main activity, and keep fullscreen activity seperate from main activity i.e. total exo code should go in fullscreen.

Comment: Yes, plus I would like to use the previwseekbar.
But there are some doubts.

Answer (score 0):

This is how worked it out to enable full screen experience with exoplayer,

In the portrait mode , layout has exoplayer view covering half of screen area with other views e.g textview, button and have a separate layout for landscape with exoplayer view matching parent and setting other views as gone.

Portrait :

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/primary_light"
    tools:context=".ui.main.ViewRecipeStepFragment"
>

    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
        android:id="@+id/ep_video_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/horizontalHalf"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/horizontalHalf"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/recipe_step_instruction"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="256dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/recipe_step_instruction"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/horizontalHalf"
        tools:text="Instructions"
    />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

To get better experience in portrait you can hide system controls using something like this (this would hide app bars), (you can call this in onCreate() or onResume() of activity)

```
    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
    private void hideSystemUi() {
        playerView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
    }
```

Finally in the landscape mode, update layout to something similar,

Landscape:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.main.ViewRecipeStepFragment"
    android:background="@color/primary_light"
>

    <com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView
        android:id="@+id/ep_video_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```